# Reinstall Ubuntu with more hard drive space

Tags: re-installation

Kind of a weird situation, but the thing is that I have installed Ubuntu alongside with the Windows 7 copy that came with my PC. Now, installing from disc did not work, so i used wubi, and stupid as i was, I just dedicated 1 GiB of space to Ubuntu. Now i want to erase Ubuntu (the 1 GiB) and install it again with something like 90-100 GiB of space, but I do not know how I can do it easily. Please, if you have an easy solution, help me!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just uninstall Wubi as it's just a program within your Windows 7 and reinstall Wubi and choose your desired space. This guide might help you:  [WubiGuide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide)